# iOS Testflight - App not processed due to app thinning with no variants

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Since updating to Xcode 13, TestFlight builds get stuck in 'Processing' indefinitely. Every time I call Apple they give me the error:

*Your app was not processing due to app thinning with no variants. For more information please visit
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/#/devbbdc5ce4f.*

Bit code was enabled (accidentally) so I disabled it on the target/project, as I cannot use it due to a dependency. This is a react native app so I believe no asset catalog is needed?

I also locally exported the archive as **Ad Hoc** and **rebuild from bitcode** with **App Thinning enabled** for **All compatible device variants** with no errors. It creates an App thinning report and all the required ipas.

Is there anywhere else I should be looking for App Thinning related settings or another way to diagnose the issue?

Comment: maybe this link be helpful: https://ankur-s20.medium.com/implementing-app-thinning-in-your-project-step-by-step-tutorial-ios-app-b3cfd139896d

Comment: Is this issue still reproduced? I listen to this issue at the same time, but it was Apple trouble and now it's fixed.

Comment: Yes, now I get a specific error when I try and upload a build - I get asset validation failed which points to a 3rd party framework with an invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value for iPhoneSimulator. I guess Apple must have changed something on their end

Answer (score 0):

After changing nothing in my Xcode project I now get a specific error when I try and upload a build which was not happening previously. I get asset validation failed (kinda makes sense as it is related to app thinning) which points to a 3rd party framework with an invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value for iPhoneSimulator. I guess Apple must have changed something on their end to show the error. Removing the iPhoneSimulator value resolved the issue